# Filter an InputStream line-by-line

Tags: java

I am retrieving large gzipped files from Amazon S3. I would like to be able to transform each line of these files on-the-fly and upload the output to another S3 bucket.

The upload API takes an [`InputStream`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#PutObjectRequest-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.InputStream-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata-) as input.

```
S3Object s3object = s3.fetch(bucket, key);

InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(s3object.getObjectContent());

// . . . ?

s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, is, metadata));
```

I believe that the most efficient way of doing this is to create my own custom input stream which transforms the original input stream into another input stream. I am not very familiar with this approach and curious to find out more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is as follows.

It's not terribly efficient but should get the job done.

```
public class MyInputStream extends InputStream {

    private final BufferedReader input;
    private final Charset encoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    private ByteArrayInputStream buffer;

    public MyInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, this.encoding));
        nextLine();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (buffer == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        int ch = buffer.read();
        if (ch == -1) {
            if (!nextLine()) {
                return -1;
            }
            return read();
        }
        return ch;
    }

    private boolean nextLine() throws IOException {
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            line = filterLine(line);
            if (line != null) {
                line += '\n';
                buffer = new ByteArrayInputStream(line.getBytes(encoding));
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        input.close();
    }

    private String filterLine(String line) {
        // Filter the line here ... return null to skip the line
        // For example:
        return line.replace("ABC", "XYZ");
    }

}
```

`nextLine()` pre-fills the line buffer with a (filtered) line. Then `read()` (called by the upload job) fetches bytes from the buffer one-by-one and calls `nextLine()` again to load the next line.

Use as:

```
s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, new MyInputStream(is), metadata));
```

A performance improvement could be to also implement the `int read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` method (if cpu use is high) and use a `BufferedInputStream` in case the S3 client doesn't internally use a buffer (I don't know).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Should `nextLine();` be called from `read();` rather than the constructor?

Comment: Did you specify the content length? S3 appears to [require](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html) the content length. Which means you need to buffer the entire object somewhere or fetch it twice.

Comment: In my implementation I extended FilterInputStream instead of InputStream which also required read(bytes, offset, length) to be implemented. Keep in mind this examples always adds a trailing new line regardless if the source has one but that's often what you would want anyways but I made this optional.

Answer (score -3):

```
new BufferedReader(is).lines()
```

Comment: @gygabyte only has 40 reputations, he/she cannot make a comment

Comment: `BufferedReader` has no constructor taking in `InputStream`.